# ExtJS String to Combobox

Tags: php, extjs, combobox

I have a php file that returns a string like this

```
["item1","item2","item3","item4"]
```

I need to create a combobox with ExtJS. The options must be the items like 4 options. How would I do this if the php link is `items.php`. Just to make things clear I need the `combobox displayField` and `valueField` have the same values, like the `item1` will be the `displayField` and the `valueField`. Thanks in advance!

P.S. the string is not Json formatted, I guess it's array store.

Comment: @TheHorse I believe its versio 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I think you have to modify your php script so that it returns string at least like this `[["item1"],["item2"],["item3"],["item4"]]`. Otherwise you will have to create your own extjs reader or override Ext.data.reader.Array.read method.

Secondly, your store should look like this:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  fields: ['item'],
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/items.php',
    reader: {
      type: 'array'
    }
  }
}
```

Thirdly, your combo config should look like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
  store: store,
  displayField: 'item',
  valueField: 'item'
});
```

If you decide to use your original php script anyway you can take a look at [how to define your own reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725453/how-to-create-ext-data-store-from-an-unusal-json-store/6731073#6731073) (There is json reader discussed, but you can figure out how to implement that code in your array reader)

Comment: I'd add that the array does need to be JSON-formatted (it looks like it is from the example) and that it's [bad practice to return top-level arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833299/can-an-array-be-top-level-json-text#answer-3833393) as an HTTP response.

Comment: To just let you know how I did this, I created a function with javascript that returns the string, then used substr and edited the string to the format I wanted, it works fine now, thanks for everyone's help. :) It's really nice knowing people care and help.